# Byte Code File for Python

Tags: python, bytecode

I am unable to see Compiled Python File (Byte Code) on my hard drive.
I can only see script file with py extension but no Compiled file with pyc extension

I have Windows 7 OS installed.

Comment: Have you checked if its hidden?

Comment: Do you have a write access in the directory from which *.py files are imported?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only imported modules get a byte-code cache, a `.pyc` file. For the main script file, the one you run first, *no* byte cache file is created.

Bytecode cache files are only created if Python has write access to the file system.

For Python 3.2 newer, these bytecode files have been moved to a subdirectory called `__pycache__`, see [PEP 3147](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3147/).

If you do not see a `.pyc` file for your python code, check that you:

1. you are dealing with a module, not the main script.
2. Python has write access to the filesystem
3. for Python 3.2 or newer, that you didn't miss out on the `__pycache__` directory
4. that you didn't run Python with the [`-B` command line switch](http://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#miscellaneous-options) disabling bytecode cache writing.

Answer (score 0):

You may be invoking the interpreter with the -B option.

http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#miscellaneous-options